# how to split a string with a condition in java

Tags: java, string, split

I am trying to split a string by a delimiter only in certain situations. 
To be more specific, I want to split the conditions of a split statement.
I want to be able to split

```
"disorder == 1 or ( x < 100)"
```

into

```
"disorder == 1" 
"(x < 100)"
```

If I use `split("or")` I would get a split inside `disorder` too :

```
"dis"
"der == 1"
"( x < 100)"
```

And if I try to use regex like `split("[ )]or[( ]")` I would lose the parentheses from `( x < 100)` :

```
"disorder == 1"
"x < 100)"
```

I am looking for a way to split the string only if the delimiter is surrounded by space or parentheses, but I want to keep the surroundings.

Comment: Regex is not the right tool to parse expressions. For parsing you need *parsers*.

Comment: How about splitting on spaces and parentheses, and then rejoining when the string isn't a literal "or"?

Comment: easy solution is to use the string " or " (wth spaces) as keyword to splt, else you better go with graphs and solve then backwards.

Comment: @MarcosVasconcelos note that their example has "or(". No space between the "r" and the "(".

Comment: https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use Lookaheads and Lookbehinds for the spaces/parenthesis, so something like this:

```
String input = "disorder == 1 or( x < 100)";
String[] split = input.split("(?<=[ )])or(?=[ (])");
```

- The `[ )]` and `[ (]` mean to look at spaces or parenthesis. This can of course be replaced with any other boundary characters, or even a literal regex boundary `\\b`.
- The `(?<=...)` is a positive lookbehind. So it only matches `or` when it has a space or `)` in front of it, but doesn't remove them with the split.
- The `(?=...)` is a lookahead. So it only matches `or` followed by a space or `(`, but doesn't remove them with the split.

[**Try it online.**](https://tio.run/##jYyxDoIwFEV3vuKmC22IBGYhfIGTI@lQKTFFoE1biMbw7VjQREen9@5759xOzOLQydu6Nr1wDiehxmcEmOnSqwbOCx/GrJXEEF707K0arzWHYBsGvA9Qo5k8ShCpnLaytShL5NCW4o4CeZYxcvwRQoMzvdqUXU33RAmtirIG4yyYVdgoZ4R9xIfz7ZDqAJtQ4fuRxiROdrHOeBLCP2T@JZdoWdcX)

Answer (score 3):

As flakes pointed out in the comments, you can use the [word boundary character](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html).

> The metacharacter \b is an anchor like the caret and the dollar sign. It matches at a position that is called a "word boundary". **This match is zero-length**.

```
String x = "disorder == 1 or( x < 100)";
for(String s : x.split("\\bor\\b"))
        System.out.println(s);
```

Result:

> disorder == 1
>   ( x < 100)

For a solution using lookahead/lookbehind, see Kevins excellent answer.

Comment: You dont need a lookahead or a lookbehind to match a boundary character here. Boundary characters are zero length by definition and will not modify the output. Simply use `x.split("\\bor\\b")`

Comment: @flakes thanks, I wasn't aware of that. Changed my answer accordingly

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure what you are doing this for: The example you presented gives a somehow a very small view of what you want to do and what you want to do this for. Correct me if I'm wrong but it seems that you want to parse arbitrary expressions of some kind of programming language.

In general you can't approach things like this in such a simple way. This is an expression. It has a hierarchical structure. No simple splitting - even not with RegEx - will work here in general as RegEx can not honor this hierarchical structure.

To do this properly you need to *parse* the expression to some extent. This is done by splitting the expression into simple tokens, rebuild the hierarchy in a (simple) tree data model and then you can analyze it in any way you want. Actually you can use RegEx to identify the individual tokens, but you need to build a tree-like data structure first before you can work with it.

Building this tree like structure is not so trivial as you have to consider the precedence of various operators within your expression. But iff (!) you have a very specific field of application - f.e. a list of expressions with some very limited structure - you might be able to use the token list directly.

Here's an example for this tokenization process. Your character sequence `disorder == 1 or( x < 100)` might parse into some token sequence such as this:

- W:"disorder"
- OP:"=="
- NUM:"1"
- W:"or"
- B:"("
- W:"x"
- OP:"<"
- NUM:"100"
- B:")"

Now you can identify the word "or" and deal with the expression the way you want.

The trick then would be to perform reasonable tokenization. For this I recommend to define a set of regular expressions, each one recognizing either a number, a word or some operator or bracket. Process each string by looking at the next characters with each individual RegEx, try to match these characters with these regular expressions. If you have a match, emit a token as you have found one, then advance to the position in your character sequence after the match to then continue with the rest of your character sequence.

If you have been able to pass through the character sequence (and emitting tokens), then parsing is successfully completed. If you fail with all individual RegExes provided, there is some syntactical problem in the input data. After tokenization you can further do with your tokens whatever you want.

Comment: you are right !  I am trying to parse expression  for a programming language. I am putting the expressions in a tree, each node being a class that implements an expression Interface, and I have the operations with higher priority lower in the tree. The only method of the interface is evaluate, that evaluates addExpr() as a + b , mullExpr() as a * b and so on. The parser goes on levels and splits the string holding the whole expression into sub-strings that will be evaluated by the same parser but on a higher level. I had such splitters for all the other operations , but not not for AND and OR

Comment: If you want to do that "by hand" (= without compiler building tools) first design a grammar (which is absolutely essential for your task), then implement a simple recursive decent parser after you've the tokens in order to build the AST. But this is a bit more complex to answer in a simple Stack Overflow question as it will be quite a bit of code. But there are tutorials about this on the internet and there are books about this topic. My advice: Get some books and do some Google search for code examples. From my own experience I can tell you: You'll be successful this way :-)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to have a more complex regular expression where the word "or" plus a single preceding and succeeding character are non alphabetic.  For example:

```
((.+)+(\Wor\W)+)+
```

Something like this, where you identify the pattern of characters, a separating non-word character, the literal word "or", and another separating non-word character.  This may not be the exact form you need, but something similar to this that captures the pattern would probably work for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can just replace the or into anything else that's not in the string and split it by that charachter.

For example:

```
String [] n = input.replace("or(",":(").split(":");
```